# Oracle is not accepting VARCHAR

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
    CustomerMobileNumber CHAR(10),
    CustomerName&Address VARCHAR(255)
)
```

As far I am aware the syntax is correct, I have tried VARCHAR2 but it is not working either.
Does anyone know what to do with this? Im sure its an easy fix

Comment: CustomerName&Address I suspect is invalid identifier. Please try CustomerNameAndAddress

Comment: Oracle is not accepting your invalid object name, it's nothing to do with the data type.

Comment: Also you might consider a column that combines a name and address means your data is not normalised and will probably cause you no-end of future issues.

Answer (score 3):

As you were told (in comments), it is not about datatype - although Oracle **recommends** we use `varchar2` instead of `varchar` - it is about invalid column name, as it contains the `&` character so Oracle *presumes* you tried to put datatype here:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Customer
  2  (
  3     CustomerMobileNumber   CHAR (10),
  4     CustomerName&Address   VARCHAR2 (255)
  5  );
   CustomerName&Address   VARCHAR2 (255)
               *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00902: invalid datatype
```

One option - which is what you should really use - is to normalize table. Keeping name and address in the same column is most probably a wrong choice.

Another one is to rename column so that it uses valid characters only. Note that Oracle isn't case-sensitive in that matter, so although you use mixed letter case, column names will be stored in uppercase in data dictionary so you'd rather use underline to separate words.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Customer
  2  (
  3     CustomerMobileNumber   CHAR (10),
  4     CustomerNameAddress    VARCHAR2 (255)
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> desc customer
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 CUSTOMERMOBILENUMBER                               CHAR(10)
 CUSTOMERNAMEADDRESS                                VARCHAR2(255)
```

vs.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Customer
  2  (
  3     Customer_Mobile_Number      CHAR (10),
  4     Customer_Name_and_Address   VARCHAR2 (255)
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> desc customer
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 CUSTOMER_MOBILE_NUMBER                             CHAR(10)
 CUSTOMER_NAME_AND_ADDRESS                          VARCHAR2(255)

SQL>
```

Yet another option is to enclose names into double quotes (which is another bad idea, as you'll have to use double quotes and match letter case every time you reference that table). Moreover, if you have *bad luck* and tool asks you to provide substitution variable's value (which is recognized because you used `&`), you'd get

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Customer
  2  (
  3     CustomerMobileNumber     CHAR (10),
  4     "CustomerName&Address"   VARCHAR2 (255)
  5  );
Enter value for address:
old   4:    "CustomerName&Address"   VARCHAR2 (255)
new   4:    "CustomerName"   VARCHAR2 (255)

Table created.

SQL> desc customer
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 CUSTOMERMOBILENUMBER                               CHAR(10)
 CustomerName                                       VARCHAR2(255)
```

so you'd

```
SQL> set define off
SQL> CREATE TABLE Customer
  2  (
  3     "CustomerMobileNumber"   CHAR (10),
  4     "CustomerName&Address"   VARCHAR2 (255)
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> desc customer
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 CustomerMobileNumber                               CHAR(10)
 CustomerName&Address                               VARCHAR2(255)

SQL>
```

---

Now you have various options, pick the one you find the most appropriate.